# What is the Android equivalent to a Menu Item?

Tags: android-layout, user-interface, visual-studio-2013, xamarin.android, expandablelistview

I am taking baby steps in porting an existing "Windows Forms" app (Compact Framework/Windows CE app that runs on a handheld device) to Android (to begin with - IOS and Windows Phone later) using Xamarin in Visual Studio.

The legacy main form contains a menu item; I don't see an analagous control in the "Android/Xamarin" Toolbox within Visual Studio.

Should I use the ExpandableListView control/widget, or what is the standard menu replacement for Android?

### UPDATE

Here's what the menu looks like on the stone tablet/abacus:

[image]

### UPDATE 2

After reducing my "minimum Android to target" version from 15 to 7 in the project properties, I was able to run it, but it is taller than the Empire State Building, and has no "menu bar":

[image]

Comment: What does this "Menu" look like? It's possible you may want to use an ExpandableListView, but hard to say really.

Comment: The Update shows it in all its non-glory.

Comment: Would you please read the links in my answer! :( Again in the first link: "The ActionBar APIs were first added in Android 3.0 (API level 11) **but they are also available in the Support Library for compatibility with Android 2.1 (API level 7) and above.**" Please take the time and read it :)

Comment: Thanks; I looked them over, and am not sure that's really what I want to use. I may, but am also thinking about using the ExpandableListView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Android 3.0+:**

Since Android 3 there is the Action bar http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html. I would prefer this to do it the "android way".

**Android < 3.0:**

If you need to support earlier verions of android, you can use the old menus http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#options-menu or bring the action bar to it with action bar sherlock.

For Xamarin you can also use the Actionbar Sherlock component: http://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/XamarinActionBarSherlock or create your own binding.

**Usage:**

You need to set the Style (Theme) to Holo. You can do this in the code.

```cs
[Activity(Label = "Foobar", MainLauncher = true, Theme = "@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light")]
public class MainActivity : Activity { ... }
```

The action bar will be displayed where the red arrow points:

[image]

Comment: Version 4 is Ice Cream Sandwich, right? That's the project I selected, yet I see no "ActionBar" widget in the toolbox...

Comment: The Action bar is part of the Activity (as I believe). See my first link: _"On API level 11 or higher
The action bar is included in all activities that use the Theme.Holo theme (or one of its descendants), which is the default theme when either the targetSdkVersion or minSdkVersion attribute is set to "11" or higher. If you don't want the action bar for an activity, set the activity theme to Theme.Holo.NoActionBar."_

Comment: So it sounds like I should have it; My "Compile using Android version", "Minimum Android to Target" and "Target Android version" are all set to "API Level 15 (Xamarin.Andrloid v4.0.3 Support); yet I don't have it in my toolbar; is there something else I need to do to explicitly say I want the ActionBar?

Comment: As I understand it -sorry I din't use it yet- you just have to set the Style to Holo and you will see it. `[Activity(Label = "Foobar", MainLauncher = true, Theme = "@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light")] MyActivity : Activity { ... }`

Comment: I don't understand why changing the decorator on the Activity would manipulate what is in the toolbox, but I did try that like so:
[Activity(Label = "HHSMobile", MainLauncher = true, Theme = "@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light", Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
...no difference, though...still no ActionBar in the toolbox.

Comment: It's no component you can find in the toolbox. It's shown automatically on top.

Comment: I'm confused; if it just automatically displays, how can you declare which menu items you want it to have?

Comment: The first link in my answer answers this question ;) See _"Adding Action items"_ http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionItems

Answer (score 0):

It's really not hard at all (once you know how).

Droidio (Android Studio), anyway, automatically adds an .xml file for each Activity, in the \menu folder, with a default "settings" menu item.

Using that item as a template, it's easy to ex[pa,te]nd it to include other menu items, as I have here added one for "Fetch Vendors":

[image]

So these contents in main.xml :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="hhs.app.MainActivity" >

    <item android:id="@+id/newdelivery"
        android:title="@string/new_delivery"
        android:orderInCategory="10"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item android:id="@+id/newinventory"
        android:title="@string/new_inventory"
        android:orderInCategory="20"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item android:id="@+id/deletefetched"
        android:title="@string/delete_fetched"
        android:orderInCategory="30"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item android:id="@+id/verifycode"
        android:title="@string/verify_code"
        android:orderInCategory="40"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item android:id="@+id/hhssettings"
        android:title="@string/hhs_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="50"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

give you:

[image]